# upload image files can not be displayed

Tags: php

why images can not be performed when added

```
if(isset($_POST['tambah'])){
        $data1 = array(
            'id' => $_POST['id'],
            'nama' => $_POST['nama'],
            'jk' => $_POST['jk'],
            'tempat' => $_POST['tempat'],
            'tanggal' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("$_POST[tanggal]")),

            'pekerjaan' => $_POST['pekerjaan'],
            'alamat' => $_POST['alamat'],
            'foto' => move_uploaded_file($FILES['photo']['temp_name'], '..asset/img/anggota/'.str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['id'].'.jpg'))
);
```

use function :

```
function tambahAnggota($data1){

        $kunci = implode(", ",array_keys($data1));

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_int($value)){
                $arrayValue[$i] = "'".$value."'"; 
            }else{
                $arrayValue[$i] = $value;
            }
        $i++;
        }


        $nilai = implode(", ", $arrayValue);
print_r($nilai);
        die();
        $s = "insert into anggota ($kunci)";
        $s .= " VALUES ";
        $s .= "($nilai)";
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($s); /*or die ($this->db->connect_errno);*/

        $sql->execute();
}
```

will be added all the data except the image data file to be uploaded
will look like this :

'DA123', 'David', 'laki', 'Los Angeles', '1987-03-12', 'Web Developer', 'foof st.', ''

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your path : you write '..asset/img/anggota/' which is not correct.

Try with ../asset/img/anggota/ (notice the **/** after **..**).

Just replace  :

```
'foto' => move_uploaded_file($FILES['photo']['temp_name'], '..asset/img/anggota/'.str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['id'].'.jpg'))
```

With :

```
'foto' => move_uploaded_file($FILES['photo']['temp_name'], '../asset/img/anggota/'.str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['id'].'.jpg'))
```